# How Spark broadcast the data in Broadcast Join

Tags: apache-spark, scala-spark

How Spark broadcast the data when we use Broadcast Join with hint - As I can see when we use the broadcast hint: It calls this function

```scala
 def broadcast[T](df: Dataset[T]): Dataset[T] = {
    Dataset[T](df.sparkSession,
      ResolvedHint(df.logicalPlan, HintInfo(strategy = Some(BROADCAST))))(df.exprEnc)
  }
```

Which internally calls the apply method of dataset & set the logicalPlan using ResolvedHint

```scala
val dataset = new Dataset(sparkSession, logicalPlan, implicitly[Encoder[T]])
```

But what is after this. How this actually work, where is code written for that.

1. What if we have multiple partitions of small dataset (which we are going to broadcast), does spark combine all partitions & then broadcast?
2. Does it broadcast to driver first & then it goes executors.
3. What is BitTorrent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding 1 & 2 During broadcast join data are collected on driver and what is going on later depends on join algorith

For **BroadcastHashJoin(BHJ)** driver builds hashtable and then this table is distributed to executors

For **BroadcastNestedLoops** broadcasted dataset is distributed as array to executors

So as you can see initial structure is not kept here and whole broadcasted dataset needs to fit into driver's memory (otherwise job will fail with oom error on driver)

Regarding 3 what exactly do you want to know?

In spark there is TorrentBroadcast which is BitTorrent-like implementation of broadcast. I don't know much about it (i never had to dig so deep), but if you want to know more i think that you can start here:

[TorrentBroadcast docu](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/broadcast/TorrentBroadcast.html)

[TorrentBroadcast source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/broadcast/TorrentBroadcast.scala)

[HttpBroadcast docu](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/broadcast/HttpBroadcast.html) - its other broadcast algorithm

Comment: For broadcasting the Dataset Spark use Torrent - is that right?
I have seen the torrent docs, It is mainly written for broadcast variable.
Also how spark decide to go for BHJ or BNL

Comment: Yes, it will be TorrentBroadcast. I checked Spark 3 code and from what i can see HttpBroadcast was removed and now the only option is torrent. When it comes to BHJ vs SMJ and BNL, Spark is going to choose join algorithm during planning, i think that this comment from source code is describing in a short which strategy is used:  [Spark source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/1e305643b3b4adfbfdab8ed181f55ea2e6b74f0d/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala#L209) check the second part of the comment, regarding case without hints.